# Splunk inputs configuration cron schedule for powershell stanza

Tags: powershell, permissions, splunk

I have a power shell stanza in my etc/system/local/inputs.conf in my forwarder server which goes as follows.

```
[powershell://SomeSessions]
disabled = 0
script = net session
schedule = */5 * * * *
sourcetype = Some_Shared_User_Sessions
index=Some_Monitoring
```

I was able to get data to enterprise every 5 mins but after few hours it stops sending data from the power shell source.

I am not sure if the problem is with permissions to run power shell scripts or something else. Can anyone help?

Comment: If it was a permissions problem you probably wouldn't get any data at all.  Check splunkd.log on the forwarder.

Comment: Appreciate for the information. But didn't find much info from the logs. 

And the problem is only with powershell source. I am reading data from disk and services source windows host logs

Comment: Verify the account running Splunk is allowed to run PowerShell scripts. I believe the default is to block unsigned scripts.